# Which 1x2 brick design is older?

Tags: part-identification, history, harry-potter

I was trying to rebuild the LEGO Harry Potter Hogwarts Castle from 2001 and I’ve noticed that at some point they changed the 1x2’s model. Which design is older?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remember seeing some new bricks reusing (probably updated) older variation of the mould. So this kind of information isn't always accurate.

Here what Rebrickable tells about variations of Brick 1 x 2:

> There are three known mold versions of this part:
>
> [3065](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3065/) Brick 1 x 2 without Bottom Tube This is the original version,
> introduced in 1955. The inside has no bottom tube. While it was
> replaced by a tubed version in 1959, it was kept in production for
> transparent colors.
>
> [3004](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3004/) Brick 1 x 2 with Open Bottom Tube This seems to be the modern
> version. The bottom tube is open.
>
> [3004](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3004/) Brick 1 x 2 with Solid Bottom Tube This seems to be an older
> version. The bottom tube is solid.

[image]

And since Rebrickable's idea is to keep accurate inventories for each set they have following disclaimer for this brick:

> The mold comparison image shows all three versions. As long as we are unsure when the mold change of 3004 happened, we  cannot create different parts for these molds.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see if they have cross-members in your photo, as can be seen in the other answer. If the solid one doesn't have them, then it is definitely older. Probably they made the two changes at different times and kept hollow pillars and the one with the solid pillar is older anyway.

Comment: Hi Andrew, and welcome to Bricks SE! Requesting further information is better suited for comments on the original question, rather than answers.