Transparent 1x2 bricks with no clutch power
I recently picked up a bag of odd bricks from my local LEGO store, from the bins where they resell bricks they've bought by weight. Amongst them were a bunch of 1x2 transparent bricks with no middle tube. Amazingly, their studs have literally no clutching power at all! From the bottom they sit tightly.
I'm questioning whether these are real LEGO bricks at all, but the studs do read "LEGO". On the underside there's number 45. What kind of a problem is this?? I did some searching but if anything, old bricks are said to become tighter, not more loose.



First off: you're probably dealing with part 3065 "Brick 1 x 2 without Bottom Tube", which is different from part 3004 "Brick 1 x 2". See also https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/16678/13403 , where different designs of the 1x2 brick are discussed.
Second: Transparent bricks are made of a different material (polycarbonate) than opaque bricks (ABS plastic) (See also: How has the basic brick changed over the years?). Polycarbonate ages differently than ABS, so the properties of aged transparent bricks can be different from aged opaque bricks.
I see no reason to doubt those are legitimate LEGO bricks.

I'm assuming part 3065 was designed for cases where it looking clear was more important than maintaining clutch power for ever and ever.  Part 3004 is for where the structural integrity wins out over aesthetics.

This is no limited to old/aged parts. Even new/modern transparent plates/bricks typically have less clutch power than their non-transparent counterparts.

The closest piece I can think of to the one shown above is the transparent Lego tile in the 2x1 stud size. The 2x1 "jumper" tile also has no tubes.

looks like you referring to part #3794b - Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove (Jumper) in Trans-Clear.
